# Rsyslog: discarding specific messages, rate limiting

Tags: rsyslog

I've got `netatalk` installed on the server and `afpd` is spamming system logs with the following error:

```
Jun 24 15:38:16 TEST afpd[21532]: sys_getextattr_size: error: Operation not supported
```

I'm not sure what's the actual root cause for this so I tried to discard this error message by adding the following line into `rsyslog.conf` config file:

```
if ($programname == 'afpd') then ~
```

It's no longer logged but it looks like `afpd` is still logging a lot:

```
Jun 24 15:46:31 TEST rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 13 messages from pid 35381 due to rate-limiting
Jun 24 15:46:31 TEST rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 34080 due to rate-limiting
```

The `35381` and `34080` are `afpd` PIDs.

When I disabled the rate limiting (`$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0`) the messages are no longer logged so I'm not quite sure what's going on there.

**Questions:**

- why messages are not logged when rate limiting is disabled
- how I can permanently discard logs from `afpd` daemon

**Edit: Wed Jul  2 14:41:34 BST 2014:**

- System: CentOS release 6.4
- rsyslog-5.8.10-6.el6.x86_64

Default configuration, I just added this line `if ($programname == 'afpd') then ~` to `rsyslog.conf` config file.

Comment: rsyslog package version, distro version, complete configuration?

Comment: Please see my update from `Wed Jul 2 14:41:34 BST 2014`.

Comment: Cannot you instead configure afpd itself? E.g. change log level of afpd to LOG_SEVERE, as described in http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/2.2/htmldocs/afpd.conf.5.html (search for Logging options).

Comment: It seems to be working fine: You are dropping them with the "~" action.  If you have rate limiting on, imuxsock (the input layer) is noting that apfd is generating a lot of logs that are then rate limited, before being dropped by the "~" action.  If you then disable rate limiting, all of the messages are received by imuxsock, then hit the "~" action and are dropped.

Answer (score 1):

may be offtopic, but

> When I disabled the rate limiting ($SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0) the
>   messages are no longer logged so I'm not quite sure what's going on
>   there.

need more parameters to disable rsyslog limit
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/156863

```
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 0
$IMUXSockRateLimitBurst 0
$IMUXSockRateLimitInterval 0
$IMUXSockRateLimitSeverity 7
```